Lib working in netlify dev, in netlify preview PR but not in production (Nuxt)
I have a lib that is working when it is deployed in preview, it also works on the dev server but it does not work when the server runs in standalone mode. I get the following error in the client console:
Object { message: 'invalid line (no token ";" or ":") "<!DOCTYPE html><html  data-capo=""><head><meta charset="utf-8">"', name: "ParserError", stack: "f._handleContentLine@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:31:1198\nf/<@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:31:119\nf._eachLine@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:33:107\nf@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:31:91\nparseEvents@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:34:55022\ngetEvents@https://iut-onboardin.netlify.app/_nuxt/Bu-f8MEs.js:24:43386\n" }
Here is my source code where this problem happens.
The NodeJS version running in deploy environment is the same as the one on my machine (v18.20.4)
Here are the deploy logs.
I already tried many fixes but nothing is working, from using the official $fetch from Nuxt to the classic fetch of JavaScript.
PS: For mods, if I didn't format my post correctly I am sorry about this. For other peaple, sorry for my English.

Latest LTS of node is v20, in a week it will be v22, I recommend to upgrade overall. Also your logs look just fine (all green). Also you use the app as SSR, I'm not sure that Netlify gives you a full-time running Node server. Hence why it works locally but not remotely. Do you mind doing some SSG rather (nuxt generate)? I also recommend trying to setup the workflow first, because it's usually easier to debug for when you need to actually deploy the app.

Thank you for your comment, I will give this a shot.

Any success with the environment?

Sadly it is still not working. So i am reconding the entire backend for this...

Why? Swap it to SSG and it will work. You don't need to recode the entire backend. Also, what is not working when shipping as a static app?

Well the thing is, it is the whole proxy system that does not work anymore. In fact, we are trying to fetch Hyperplanning, but hyperplanning denies EVERY request made by fetch, even in CORS mode. So i have to redo the entire backend with a new proxy. In fact, it is already recoded

Just fix CORS rather than using some backend to solve that issue. You could solve CORS issue by proxying to a backend but you can also simply allow your frontend endpoint haha, why wasting time redoing everything?

No, with Hyperplanning, you CAN'T fix the cors without a proxy. But the backend that was in place was not designed to work with a proxy, so I had to do it all over again.

I did the backend all over again with a proxy endpoint so now it is working. The library was trying to hit a URL that should have been handled by netlify but it was not. So now the lib is gone and everything works.
